# How to calculate 5 day-mean, 10-day mean & 15-day mean for given data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

**Scenario :**

I have following dataframe as below

````
```     -- -----------------------------------
        companyId | calc_date   | mean   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 01-08-2002  |  15    |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 02-08-2002  |  16.5   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 03-08-2002  |  17     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 04-08-2002  |  15     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 05-08-2002  |  23     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 06-08-2002  |  22.6   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 07-08-2002  |  25     | 
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 08-08-2002  |  15     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 09-08-2002  |  15     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 10-08-2002  |  16.5   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 11-08-2002  |  22.6   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 12-08-2002  |  15     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 13-08-2002  |  16.5   |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 14-08-2002  |  25     |
        ----------------------------------
        1111      | 15-08-2002  |  16.5   |
        ----------------------------------

```
````

**Required :**

Need to calculate for given data 5 day-mean , 10-day mean , 15-day mean for every record for every company.

```
5 day-mean   -->  Previous 5 days available mean sum
10 day-mean  --> Previous 10 days available mean sum
15 day-mean  --> Previous 15 days available mean sum
```

Resultant dataframe should have caluluated columns as below

```
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        companyId | calc_date   | mean   |  5 day-mean | 10-day mean | 15-day mean |
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Question :**
    How to achieve this ?
    What is the best way to do this in spark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using Window partitions by company to compute the `n-day mean` between the current row and previous rows within the specified timestamp range via `rangeBetween`, as shown below (using a dummy dataset):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = (1 to 3).flatMap(i => Seq.tabulate(15)(j => (i, s"${j+1}-2-2019", j+1))).
  toDF("company_id", "calc_date", "mean")

df.show
// +----------+---------+----+
// |company_id|calc_date|mean|
// +----------+---------+----+
// |         1| 1-2-2019|   1|
// |         1| 2-2-2019|   2|
// |         1| 3-2-2019|   3|
// |         1| 4-2-2019|   4|
// |         1| 5-2-2019|   5|
// |         ...             |
// |         1|14-2-2019|  14|
// |         1|15-2-2019|  15|
// |         2| 1-2-2019|   1|
// |         2| 2-2-2019|   2|
// |         2| 3-2-2019|   3|
// |         ...             |
// +----------+---------+----+

def winSpec = Window.partitionBy("company_id").orderBy("ts")
def dayRange(days: Int) = winSpec.rangeBetween(-(days * 24 * 60 * 60), 0)

df.
  withColumn("ts", unix_timestamp(to_date($"calc_date", "d-M-yyyy"))).
  withColumn("mean-5", mean($"mean").over(dayRange(5))).
  withColumn("mean-10", mean($"mean").over(dayRange(10))).
  withColumn("mean-15", mean($"mean").over(dayRange(15))).
  show
// +----------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+-------+
// |company_id|calc_date|mean|        ts|mean-5|mean-10|mean-15|
// +----------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+-------+
// |         1| 1-2-2019|   1|1549008000|   1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
// |         1| 2-2-2019|   2|1549094400|   1.5|    1.5|    1.5|
// |         1| 3-2-2019|   3|1549180800|   2.0|    2.0|    2.0|
// |         1| 4-2-2019|   4|1549267200|   2.5|    2.5|    2.5|
// |         1| 5-2-2019|   5|1549353600|   3.0|    3.0|    3.0|
// |         1| 6-2-2019|   6|1549440000|   3.5|    3.5|    3.5|
// |         1| 7-2-2019|   7|1549526400|   4.5|    4.0|    4.0|
// |         1| 8-2-2019|   8|1549612800|   5.5|    4.5|    4.5|
// |         1| 9-2-2019|   9|1549699200|   6.5|    5.0|    5.0|
// |         1|10-2-2019|  10|1549785600|   7.5|    5.5|    5.5|
// |         1|11-2-2019|  11|1549872000|   8.5|    6.0|    6.0|
// |         1|12-2-2019|  12|1549958400|   9.5|    7.0|    6.5|
// |         1|13-2-2019|  13|1550044800|  10.5|    8.0|    7.0|
// |         1|14-2-2019|  14|1550131200|  11.5|    9.0|    7.5|
// |         1|15-2-2019|  15|1550217600|  12.5|   10.0|    8.0|
// |         3| 1-2-2019|   1|1549008000|   1.0|    1.0|    1.0|
// |         3| 2-2-2019|   2|1549094400|   1.5|    1.5|    1.5|
// |         3| 3-2-2019|   3|1549180800|   2.0|    2.0|    2.0|
// |         3| 4-2-2019|   4|1549267200|   2.5|    2.5|    2.5|
// |         3| 5-2-2019|   5|1549353600|   3.0|    3.0|    3.0|
// +----------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+-------+
// only showing top 20 rows
```

Note that one could use `rowsBetween` (as opposed to `rangeBetween`) directly on `calc_date` if the dates are guaranteed to be contiguous per-day time series.

Comment: thank you so much . Let me apply and update you.
What is "ts" here in this method i.e. 
    def winSpec = Window.partitionBy("company_id").orderBy("ts")

Comment: `ts` is [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  It is generated from `calc_date` via `unix_timestamp()` in the first `withColumn()`.

Comment: Leo any clue how to approach the solution for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416623/how-to-group-dataframe-year-wise-and-iterate-through-groups-and-send-each-year-d

Comment: how I can get the mean based on calendar date for 5 day , 10-day means instead of rangeBetween i.e. which gives based on timestamp?

Comment: @Shyam, by converting the string-type `calc_date` to unix timestamp `ts` as the basis for `rangeBetween`, it's already computing the means based on actual calendar dates.

Comment: thank you , so I need to convert the given date (dd-MM-yyyy) to unix ts then apply .over(dayRange(5))) then i would get 5 days mean right?

Comment: Correct.  That's what the existing solution is already doing – the converted `ts` in the first `withColumn` is for `partitionBy().orderBy("ts").rangeBetween()` to compute the means using actual date value (in unix timestamp).

Comment: thank you so much , Leo any idea of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037648/how-to-send-each-group-at-a-time-to-the-spark-executors   , how to approach  ??

Comment: How can I calculate Standard Deviation on 180 days mean data  how to do it?

Comment: @Shyam, you should be able to replace `mean() over dayRange()` with [stddev()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@stddev(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) over `dayRange()` in the answer to get what you want.

Comment: are you on IM Gitter ?  is this possible in spark  ""is there any way in spark to handle calculation in accumulated way ? i.e. I have a scenario where i will load 1 million company values and process them ....next day i will have further more 100,000 company information ingested , I need to calculate total 1,100,000 company calculation without recalculating earlier 1 million records .... how can this be achieved ?"""

Comment: Perhaps you could use a `where` condition to filter out rows that have `null` X-day means, if applicable.  Instead of extending questions in the comments section, I would suggest that you post a separate question about your incremental update requirement with detailed description and a minimal sample dataset.

Comment: Can you please help me what went wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080797/unable-to-write-parquet-file-due-error-sparkexception-job-aborted-fileforma