# How to send each group at a time to the spark executors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm unable to send each group of dataframe at a time to the executor.

I have a data as below in `company_model_vals_df dataframe`.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | model_id  |  fiscal_year  | fiscal_quarter | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |    1      | 2018          |   1             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    1      | 2018          |   2             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    1      | 2018          |   1             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    1      | 2018          |   2             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    1      | 2018          |   1             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    2      | 2017          |   3             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    2      | 2017          |   1             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    2      | 2017          |   3             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    2      | 2017          |   3             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 |    2      | 2017          |   1             | r1   | r2   | r3   |  r4  | r5   |  r6 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to send each grouped data to executor, to process each one at a time.

For that I am doing as below:

```
var dist_company_model_vals_df =  company_model_vals_df.select("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").distinct()

// Want to send each group at a time to write by executors.

dist_company_model_vals_df.foreach(rowDf => {
  writeAsParquet(rowDf , parquet_file)    // this simply writes the data as parquet file
})
```

**Error :**

This throws a NullPointerException as rowDf is not found on the Executor side. What is the correct way to handle this in spark-sql using Scala 2.11?

**Part 2 : Question**

When i do company_model_vals_df.groupBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year") the data is spilling a lot on disk even after i increased the memory. I.e. company_model_vals_df is huge dataframe ... lot of spilling happening when doing groupBy.

Same is the case below i.e. with partitionBy

company_model_vals_df.write.partitionBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year")

**PSEDO CODE :**
So in order to avoid is first I would do tuples of 
val groups = company_model_vals_df.groupBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").collect

```
groups.forEach{ group ->
   // I want to prepare child dataframes for each group from    company_model_vals_df

   val child_df = company_model_vals_df.where(model_id= group.model_id && fiscal_quarter === group.fiscal_quarter && etc)

 this child_df , i want wrote to a file i.e. saveAs(path)
}
```

Is there anyway to do it.
Any spark functions or API useful for me here?
please suggest a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to manipulate the data separately for each `"model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year"`.

If that's correct, you would do it with a `groupBy()`, for example:

```scala
company_model_vals_df.groupBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").agg(avg($"col1") as "average")
```

If what you're looking for is to write each logical group into a separate folder, you can do that by writing:

```scala
company_model_vals_df.write.partitionBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").parquet("path/to/save")
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. yes want to manipulate the data separately for each set of "model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year" . I have to itereate each set and save as parquet file.  If i do groupBy above , due to huge data it is spilled data on to desk and running for ever.

Comment: @dytyniak can you please have a look at the question i asked ...I need to iterate each distinct group which consists ("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year") , need to form a separate dataframe and send it to   writeAsParquet 
 as this       
dist_company_model_vals_df.foreach(rowDf => {
  writeAsParquet(rowDf , parquet_file)    // this simply writes the data as parquet file
})

Comment: @Shyam see above

Comment: thank you . can you please check question Part 2 section ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are few options here -

- you need to fork the dataset into several datasets and work them individually
  like ,

```scala
var dist_company_model_vals_list =  company_model_vals_df
  .select("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").distinct().collectAsList
```

Then filter `company_model_vals_df` with output of `dist_company_model_vals_list` list which provides several datasets that you can work independently, like

```scala
def rowList = {
import org.apache.spark.sql._
var dfList:Seq[DataFrame] = Seq()
for (data <- dist_company_model_vals_list.zipWithIndex) {
val i = data._2
val row = data.-1
val filterCol = col($"model_id").equalTo(row.get(i).getInt(0).and($"fiscal_quarter").equalTo(row.get(i).getInt(1).and($"fiscal_year").equalTo(row.get(i).getInt(2))

   val resultDf = company_model_vals_df.filter(filterCol)    
dfList +: = resultDf
      }
dfList
}
```

- If your objective is to write the data, you can use 
  `partitionBy("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year")` 
  method on dataframeWriterto write them separately.

Comment: you collected  As a List , but where the iteration of  the list items ? below gives only first set of ("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year") selection records , what about the rest of the sets ?
 
 i.e. company_model_vals_df.filter(col($"model_id").equalTo(dist_company_model_vals_list.get(0).getInt(0).and($"fiscal_quarter").equalTo(dist_company_model_vals_list.get(0).getInt(1)))

Comment: thank you , where are getting this "list" in "list.zipWithIndex" ? Let me test it

Comment: list is nothing, but dist_company_model_vals_list calculated in previous statement, updated the answer. you might need to check the syntax in an IDE and correct  minor changes. If it solves, please accept the answer.

Comment: it throws error like "value foreach is not a member of java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] " there is no "zipWithIndex " method. What will this give  val i = data._2 &  val row = data._1 ???

Comment: can you please check Part 2 question